# Oracle Query works for 19c but does not work in 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle19c

This query

```
SELECT (SELECT CERT_NBR 
        FROM (
          SELECT XREF.CERT_NBR, XREF.REQUEST_ID , XREF.AUDIT_TS 
          FROM B2B_XREF_CERT_QUOTE XREF 
          WHERE XREF.REQUEST_ID = REQ.REQUEST_ID  
          ORDER BY XREF.AUDIT_TS DESC
       ) WHERE rownum = 1) AS CERT_NBR 
FROM B2B_RT_REQUEST REQ, 
     B2B_RT_RESPONSE RES 
WHERE REQ.REQUEST_ID = RES.REQUEST_ID 
AND UPPER(TRIM(REQ.REQUEST_ID)) IN ('RF27117FE')
```

runs fine on 19c but fails on 11g , can someone tell me what is an alternative way to write the same which will work for 11g.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the query should be doing.  Also, why are you **not** using proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  This query is a part of a big query , which joins many other table. If i join on this one too , the complete query will miss fetching rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle (and MySQL) do not allow nested correlated subquery references.  You can instead use `KEEP`:

```
SELECT (SELECT MAX(CERT_NBR) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY XREF.AUDIT_TS DESC)
        FROM B2B_XREF_CERT_QUOTE XREF 
        WHERE XREF.REQUEST_ID = REQ.REQUEST_ID  
       ) AS CERT_NBR
```

You should also learn proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.